# value of textbox has changed or not

Tags: javascript

how to find whether a value of textbox has changed or not using javascript(even if we copy something and paste it using right click and paste)

Comment: Changed since when and compared to what value?

Comment: for example initially textbox was empty and now we  add content by right click and paste

Answer (score 1):

Try using the textbox onchange event

Answer (score 0):

use the keyup and click event listeners

Answer (score 0):

Go about something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id here');

elem.onchange = function(){
  // your code here......
};
```

More Info:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Comment: i have made auto grow textarea.it's working fine but when copying and pasting using right click it's not working properly.if i use onchange event in this situation it won't work either because to fire this event we need press enter or tab. please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check this on separate event and can't use onchange event, you can compare objects `defaultValue` and `value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event to track if the contents have been changed. It is also possible to compare current `input[type=text].value` to `input[type=text].defaultValue`. `defaultValue` will have the original value supplied in the value-attribute.